# First Example Encore - Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony-3.3, webpack-encore

I try to use Encore in Symfony.

[First example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html)

I run command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/encore dev
```

and this return me error:

```
path.js:7
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1211:7)
    at find (/www/testencore/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/resolve-rc.js:11:21)
    at module.exports (/www/testencore/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/config/parse-runtime.js:64:47)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/www/testencore/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/bin/encore.js:18:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue has to do with v7.1 of babel-loader. (cfr. https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/40)

You can fix the issue by adding the following line to your package.json

```
"babel-loader": "7.0"
```

After this make sure to run `yarn upgrade`, webpack-encore should work again.

Note that this is a temporary fix. You should keep an eye on the github issue to see if there's a permanent fix available.

**EDIT:** This has been fixed since `Encore 0.9.1`, updating should solve the issue.

Comment: Note that there is a command `yarn upgrade` instead of deleting the lock file and rebuilding it again.